# Send email with smtp using gmail

Tags: smtp, gmail, mule

I try to send an email using gmail and the email configuration and I have looked at the threads and I still have the same problem please someone help me, thank you. the mistake is

> Failed to route event via endpoint:  DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=smtp://user%40gmail.com:<password>@smtp.gmail.com, connector=GmailSmtpConnector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" bccAddresses="envio@gmail.com" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail" contentType="text/plain" fromAddress="user@mail.com"/>

    <flow name="mandaremailFlow">


        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/enviar" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="todo va bien" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="user@gmail.com" password="contrasena" to="envio@gmail.com" from="user@gmail.com" subject="hola amigo" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail"/>



    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as follows:

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail" contentType="text/plain" />

    <flow name="mandaremailFlow">
      <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/enviar" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <set-payload value="todo va bien" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
      <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" user="user@gmail.com" password="contrasena" to="envio@gmail.com" from="user@gmail.com" subject="hola amigo" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail" port="587"/>

</flow>
```

I tried with my gmail credentials and it worked fine. I added the port here and removed unwanted data from Global gmail connector.
Also make sure you have given access to your Gmail to send emails from other 3rd party applications

Comment: thanks, I fixed it and that was it. but an exception every time I send the email correctly and the mule platform does not take it, try to see if you get the exception locally, thanks